# ANDROID_HOME is null when android studio compiles the gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have the following gradle file:

```
/// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        def home = System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME");
        // Work around https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69270.
        File file = new File(home);
        maven {
            url new File(file.absolutePath, "/extras/android/m2repository/").toURI().toString()
        }
        maven {
            url "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots"
            credentials {
                username 'admin'
                password 'admin123'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i run gradle assemble the project runs successfully. But when the studio builds it, it throws a

```
Error:(20, 0) Ambiguous method overloading for method java.io.File#<init>.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [class java.lang.String]
    [class java.net.URI]
```

that is the home variable is null. 
Opening a command line and executing 
`echo $ANDROID_HOME` yields the correct dir. I have restarted android studio. The Android studio is on version 1.0.2 and gradle on 2.2.1.

Comment: Check "studio.sh" for env vars in use. May be "studio_home" being used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that i started it from nautilus and not from the cmd, so the env vars from bashrc are not there for some reason.

Comment: In general it doesn't set up environment variables. Why are you doing that bug workaround that needs $ANDROID_HOME in the first place? That bug seems to be obsolete.

Comment: Agreed. `mavenLocal()` should work now.

Comment: Thanks guys. mavenLocal  resolves to my home maven repository and it can't find there the android lib artifacts. They are in the repos that the SDK manager created. I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but I was still having the same problem recently. I'm setting the env variables via the .bash_profile file and was getting null values as well... This worked for me:
Start Android studio from the command line by running:

```
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
```

Maybe this can help some other people having the same problem.